# Nested initializer list c++

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I'm working on a following class representing the 15-puzzle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) :

```
class fifteen
{
private: 
   static constexpr size_t dimension = 4;

   using position = std::pair< size_t, size_t > ;

public:
   size_t table [ dimension ][ dimension ];

   size_t open_i;
   size_t open_j;

public:
   fifteen( );

   fifteen( std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list< size_t >> init );
...
}
```

I'm trying to build the constructor with the given initializer list, however I'm stuck as in I've got no clue how to approach such nested initializer lists. The default constructor looks like this:

```
fifteen::fifteen()
    :open_i(3), open_j(3)
    {
        for(auto i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            table [i/4] [i%4] = i+1
    }
```

and the initializer list one would be used like that:

```
fifteen f{ { 1, 3, 4, 12 }, { 5, 2, 7, 11 }, { 9, 6, 14, 10 }, { 13, 15, 0, 8 } } ;
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I build such a constructor? Thanks

Comment: What about changing your class to use `std::array` instead? Change `table` to `std::array<std::array<size_t, 4> 4>`, then have the constructor take a `std::array<std::array<size_t, 4>, 4>` as input instead of `std::initializer_list`. Brace initialization can be used with `std::array`, so your constructor call should be able to stay the same, but the backend logic to construct `table` would be different, and the compiler would be able to better validate the dimensions of the input.

Comment: I will try that, but I also must do it using the initializer list in a given manner unfortunately. Thank you though, that's a good idea.

Comment: An `initializer_list` is meant for specifying a variable number of values. What benefit would that be to your class? to populate a smaller portion of `table` and zero-init the rest of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it with the initializer lists, here's how if anyone's interested:

```
fifteen( std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list< size_t >> init )
{
    int pos_i = 0;
    int pos_j = 0;
    for(auto i = init.begin(); i != init.end(); ++i)
    {
        for(auto j = i->begin(); j!= i->end(); ++j)
        {
            table [pos_i][pos_j] = *j;
            pos_j++;
        }
        pos_i++;
        pos_j = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your class to use `std::array` instead.  Change `table` to `std::array<std::array<size_t, 4> 4>`, and change your constructor to take a `std::array<std::array<size_t, 4>, 4>` as input. Brace initialization can be used with `std::array`, so your constructor call should be able to stay the same, but the backend logic to construct `table` would be different, and the compiler would be able to better validate the dimensions of the input.

Try something like this:

```
class fifteen
{
private: 
    using position = std::pair< size_t, size_t > ;

public:
    static constexpr size_t dimension = 4;
    using tablearr = std::array< std::array< size_t, dimension >, dimension >;

    tablearr table;

    size_t open_i;
    size_t open_j;

public:
    fifteen( );

    fifteen( tablearr const &init );
    //...
}


fifteen::fifteen()
    :open_i(3), open_j(3)
{
    for(auto i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        table[i/4][i%4] = i+1;
}

fifteen::fifteen(tablearr const &init)
    : table(init), open_i(3), open_j(3)
{
}
```